# Laravel/PHP number formatting with preg_replace

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a JSON part of my code which saves to the database like so:

```
Bare Filter - £200.00
```

I needed to strip everything out to get 20000 I did -

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $str);
```

but for a visitor to the site i need some format to revert is back to 200.00

I have tried:

```
number_format('20000', 2, '.', '');
```

But this returns    20000.00 which is obviously not right...
Anyone have any recommendations/suggestions?

Comment: Basic mathematics 101: `number_format('20000' / 100, 2, '.', '');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
number_format(((int) '20000') / 100, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: Great thanks, obviously mathematics not my strong point hence the reason asking for help!